# How can I prove that this set is weakly closed in $L^1((0,1))$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, weak-convergence, weak-topology

> Let $g:(0,1)\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ and define $$Q_g:=\left\{f\in L^1((0,1)): |f(x)|\leq |g(x)|~~\text{for almost every}~~x\in (0,1)\right\}\subset L^1\left((0,1)\right)$$ I want to show that this set is weakly closed in $L^1((0,1))$.

My idea was to use sequences. So I wanted to pick $(f_n)_n\subset Q_g$ a sequence s.t. $f_n\stackrel{\text{weakly}}{\longrightarrow} f\in L^1((0,1))$. I need to show that $|f(x)|\leq |g(x)|$ for almost every $x$ to conclude that $Q_g$ is closed. Since $f_n\stackrel{\text{weakly}}{\longrightarrow} f$ I know that for all $L\in \left(L^1((0,1))\right)^*$ we have $L(f_n)\rightarrow L(f)\Leftrightarrow |L(f_n-f)|\rightarrow 0$. Now I wanted to look at $$\begin{align}\big||f(x)|-|g(x)|\big|&\leq |f(x)-g(x)|\\&\leq |f(x)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-g(x)|\end{align}$$But now the problem is that I don't know if $|f_n(x)-g(x)|\leq 0$ I only know that $|f_n(x)|-|g(x)|\leq 0$. And I don't see how to fix it. Could maybe someone give me a hint?

Comment: Why are you looking at that absolute value? Wouldn’t be better to look at the positive part? Small suggestion: write $Q_g$ as the intersection of two sets, respectively $\{f\in L^1\; :\;f(x)\leq |g(x)|\}$ and $\{f\in L^1\;:\;f(x)\geq-|g(x)|\}$. Then you just need to show that these two sets are weakly closed. Then, since adding a fixed function preserves weak convergence, you can reduce to show that $\{f\in L^1\; :\;f(x)\leq 0\}$, $\{f\in L^1\; :\;f(x)\geq 0\}$ are weakly closed, that is, weak limit of positive (resp. negative) functions is positive (resp. negative). Much easier to write down

Comment: @LorenzoPompili thanks for your comment. But I still struggle a bit. I still have that $|L(f_n)-L(f)|\rightarrow 0$ by assumption and want to check that $|f(x)|\leq 0$. But now do I need to chose a specific $L$ so for example the identity functional?

Comment: Be careful, you don’t want to check $|f(x)|\leq 0$ , but rather $f(x)\leq 0$. Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, you can reduce yourself to show that $\{f\in L^1\; :\;f(x)\geq 0\}$ is weakly closed. So, take $(f_n)_n$ a sequence of positive functions, $f_n\to f$ weakly. For any $h\in L^\infty$, $h\geq 0$, $0\leq L_h(f_n)\to L(f)$ as $n\to \infty$ because $f_n$ are positive, where $L_h(\phi):=\int h\phi\;dx$.

So, $\int h\phi\;dx\geq 0$ for any $h\in L^\infty$. This necessarily implies $f\geq 0$.

Comment: Sorry I am now much more confused. Why do we take a $L_h$? and why can we simply define it as the integral? Is see your point in the last comment

Comment: So, the dual space of $L^1$ is $L^\infty$ through the identification $h\mapsto L_h$. If $h\in L^\infty$, then $L_h\in (L^1)^*$. So it makes sense to consider $L_h$ as a linear functional to test the weak convergence. I use it to test the sequence $f_n$ against positive functions. I do this because it will be useful as you can see in the last line.

Comment: Ah okey I see it now thanks a lot!